# How to Get a Layout Inflater Given a Context?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am writing a custom implementation of a ListAdapter.

In its constructor, I'm taking in a Context, a resource ID (i.e. R.id.xxx representing the layout file), and a list and a map (these contain the data).

Now, the problem is that i will need a LayoutInflater to get the View object which is in the separate layout XML file.

How can I get hold of the LayoutInflater given only the Context?

Now, why I think this is possible, is that this is quite similar to what is being passed in to the constructor of an ArrayAdapter (context, resource, textViewResourceId, data array), and I figure the ArrayAdapter also has to make use of a LayoutInflater given only a Context.

But how can it be done?

Answer (score 567, accepted):

You can use the `static` [`from()` method from the `LayoutInflater` class](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from(android.content.Context)):

```
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Comment: Thanks! i was trying to find Context.getSomething().getAnotherThing().getLayoutInflater() !

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me. Every other one that I've tried so far threw an exception.

Comment: Is it expensive to get the inflater each time that is needed, meaning, do you think we should save a member of the inflater?

Comment: BTW i think we should use LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as ultimately LayoutInflater.from(context) is doing same inside.

Comment: Which is the better one??the one with **270** votes or the one with **25+** votes

Comment: The best method to use is this one LayoutInflater.from(context). It actually does the same as the answer below context.getSystemService, but since android can change the underlying methods, we should be using the parent method instead.

Answer (score 56):

You can also use this code to get LayoutInflater:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)
```

Comment: What's the difference between LayoutInflater.from(Context ctx) and this getSustemService(...) ?

Comment: +1, for nice question, in implement of method LayoutInflater.from(context) also call context.getSystemService() to get LayoutInflater Service Provider from System Manager. So may be have a litter difference in call stack.

Comment: LayoutInflater.from(context) also throw error if the inflater cannot be retreived: here the code:
    public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (LayoutInflater == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
        }
        return LayoutInflater;
    }